The Google Analytics tabs are not visible
The Google Analytics reports section is not displaying any other tabs, such as Acquisition, Landing Pages, etc. These tabs are visible from the Google Analytics home page, but they are not showing up in the reports section.


Click "Library" at the bottom of that pane. You can add whatever reports you need. Do be aware that GA4 is currently having issues with the "Conversions" report for some accounts as they are introducing the new "Key Events" nonsense.

it is already created and published, here is the screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/47557751?key=c542411c6e37ba4ede1f5d0c32328ce0

I've actually had a very similar problem with another client where their Engagement reports aren't showing, and can't be added through the Library. I think Google are currently working on GA4 (because of their shift from Conversions to Key Events and have broken something. Possibly a lesson about not making a large part of your workforce redundant there.

Thank you for your valuable response
